# FileField Permissions- How can I allow users to upload a file without giving them the ability to remove files that have been uploaded?

Tags: entities, users, files

I want to be able to upload a file into an article but without the ability to remove other files uploaded from other users to the same article.

Is it possible?

I tried the Field Permissions module; I can edit, but I cannot upload.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a second file field via the field UI; to set the permissions for a single field you could use [hook_field_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7).

Comment: Can you be more specific? I want the article to be like Dropbox, but without the ability to change other files I didn't upload.

Comment: you mean upload in the node-view, not the node-edit ?